# tvOS UIFocusGuide for multiple objects

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to manipulate the tvOS focus engine but without succes. The setup is basic: 3 small buttons and 2 full-width collectionViews, see image.
[image: tvOS Focus engine example]
What I want is 1) when you are focussed on the red border and swipe up, to go to the theaters button. (this is working) 2) When you are focussed on the green border and swipe down, to go to the "> all movies this week" button. 3) Same as (2) but for the second collectionView.

Working code for the swipe up to "Theaters" button:

```
focusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)

focusGuide.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(theatersButton.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Do I need to add a second focus guide for the 2 other buttons? If so, on which view should I add these other focusGuides? I guess I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll get what you want if you create more focus guides (one for each of your yellow rectangles) and add them to the same view as the first. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, however that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you set the `focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = yourButton`?

Comment: @Lapidus: Did you find any luck on this? I have similar kind of view in my app. Here is the stack overflow link for the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006755/manage-focus-with-multiple-controls-on-apple-tv Please help me out if you have fixed it.

Comment: @spaleja Did not.. I ended up making a different layout.. Good luck.

Comment: @Lapidus : I got the solution..

Comment: @spaleja Great. Will you answer your own question on the above link?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to add a different focus guide under each collection view and have it's preferredFocusedView set to your button.